# C++ check if a value from a vector exists in a different vector

Tags: c++

I have 3 vectors in question. Two of those vectors already contain values for example

```
v1 = {test1,test2,test3,test4,test5}
v2 = {test1, test2, random}
```

What I want to do is check if any value from v2 exists in v1 and add that value to vector called v3.
so for example when i loop through v3 the output should be : `random`
I also want to point out that v1 and v2 can be bigger in size but v1 is always bigger. 
I just need someone to help me out and point me in the right directions. Thanks

Also is there a way I could do a check lets say if all values from v2 are in v1 do this but if there is  any value from v2 is not in v2 then do a set_difference?

Comment: `random` isn't present in `v1` and `v2`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: Assuming you can sort both vectors [set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) or [set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) could work.  Your description of what you want and your output aren't exactly clear.  The description says you want to copy values that exist in both, both the output is a value that only exists in the second.

Comment: in this particular example its only in v2. But it can be any value from v2. Lets say v2 has an additional value "random2" than I want both "random" and "random2" in v3. Basically I want to append any value from v2 that is not in V1 to v3

Comment: so what you want is set_difference... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference - assuming again that vectors can be sorted

Comment: I dont know if this makes a difference but I am getting the values from V1 from a stored procedure using mysql

Comment: One more thing. Is there a way I can do a check. lets say if all values from v2 are in v1 dont do anything and if not do the set_difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned the following function will work out:

```
template<typename T>
vector<T> contain(const vector<T>& v1, const vector<T>& v2)
{
        vector<T> v3;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)v2.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < (int)v1.size(); j++) {
                        if (v2[i] == v1[j]) v3.push_back(v1[i]);
                }
        }
        return v3;
}
```

Here we just iterate through every entry of v2 and check if v1 contains it and if it does we add this value to v3. The complexity is `n^2` but `n*log(n)` can be achieved by sorting vectors if template parameter is comparable.

Comment: Can I do a check. for example if all values from v2 match v1 then do something and if any value from v2 does not exist in v1 do something else

Comment: Well you can ckeck size of the resulting vector and if it's the same as size of v2 then all values from v2 match v1, and if it's not then there exists some volue in v2 which doesn't exist in v1. As an alternative you can save v1 in the form of [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), iterate through v2 and check if it's in v1 using [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find)

Comment: but if all values of v2 match v1 then the resulting vector should be empty. I just thought of this. IF the resulting vector is not empty than means the a value from v2 didnt match v1. So I can check for emptiness in v3 to do a check

Answer (score 2):

an algorithm exists for you, [`set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 10, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 2, 4, 666, 1 };

    std::sort(begin(v1),end(v1));
    std::sort(begin(v2),end(v2));

    std::vector<int> v3;
    v3.reserve( v2.size() ); // no more than one allocation
    std::set_difference( begin(v2), end(v2),  begin(v1), end(v1), std::back_inserter(v3) );

    for( auto e : v3 ) 
        std::cout << e << ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

std::set_difference(v2.begin(), v2.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
```